# Python socketserver problem

Tags: python, tcp

I'm trying to use threading socket server

```
self.server = SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer( ( HOST, PORT ), MCRequestHandler )
```

and the destructor

```
def __del__( self ):
        self.server.shutdown();
        self.server.server_close()
        print( 'Server closed ! ' );
```

When I close the GUI the **del** function will be called, but if I want to start again the program, I get the following error message

```
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
Exception AttributeError: "'MCCommunication' object has no attribute 'server'" in <bound method MCCommunication.__del__ of <MCCommunication.MCCommunication object at 0x26867c0>> ignored
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a subclass of TCPServer, and add this to it:

```
class TCPServer(SocketServer.TCPServer):
allow_reuse_address = True
```

Basically the same as `setsockopt`, but, easier.